# Youtube button is a no-show in django-CKEditor

Tags: django

I've been following this youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6y6cn1XUfw&t=942s

Alas, no luck in terms of the youtube button showing up on the menu.
I wanted to just make the YouTube plugin a part of `toolbar_Custom` rather than creating the extra `toolbar_Special` item, but apparently it's a no-fly-zone.

Trying for the method recommended in the video doesn't work either; I get an error on the line that contains:

```
'config.extraPlugins': ','.join(['youtube', 'codesnippet']),
```

What am I missing here?

In **main/settings.py**:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'height': 250,
        'width': '100%',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Styles', 'Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Image', 'Table', 'Youtube'],
            ['TextColor', 'SpecialChar', 'CodeSnippet'],
            ['Source']
        ],
        'config.extraPlugins': ','.join(['youtube', 'codesnippet']),
    },
```

NOTE: the tutorial says to just go with `extraPlugins` in the 13th line of the settings file, but that results in the CKEditor not showing up at all, so I've added `config.`, and it runs again... Bit of a hack job if I'm honest.

In **blog/models.py**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, blank=False)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = RichTextUploadingField(
                                    null=False,
                                    blank=False,
                                    # config_name='toolbar_Custom',
                                    external_plugin_resources=[(
                                        'youtube',
                                        '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
                                        'plugin.js',
                                    )],
                                    )
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug        = models.SlugField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, help_text='<small><font color="red">don\'t. touch. the. slug. field. unless. you. mean. it.</font> (it will auto-generate, don\'t worry.)</small>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code below in your settings.py:

```
    'extraPlugins': ','.join(
        [
           'youtube',
        ]
    ),
```

And in blog/models.py check if the path is correct:

...

'/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',

...

Maybe you should change it to

'/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/**youtube/**',